# Sliding tab with calendar in fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, calendar

I am having two sliding tabs working. Now I want Calendar in one of the tab but it is giving me error.

**Error**

```
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495): Process: com.project.homepagedemo, PID: 2495
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at com.bharatwellness.mainactivities.DiaryTabOneCalorieConsumed.onCreateView(DiaryTabOneCalorieConsumed.java:66)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-16 09:58:54.437: E/AndroidRuntime(2495):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

**my oncreate method**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_one_calorie_consumed, container, false);

        _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
                + year);

        selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
        selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

        prevMonth = (ImageView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
        prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        currentMonth = (TextView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));

        nextMonth = (ImageView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
        nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        calendarView = (GridView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.calendar);

        // Initialised
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```

I have check twice but nothing should be null. As it is working if i am using it directly as in main activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
  selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
```

to

```
  selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
```

and do the same for all other `Views`.